# ScrollView height adapting to content

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I can't seem to manage this simple layout and all the tricks I find for ScrollView don't match my case.
My content has a header and a footer that should "stick" to it.
But when my content becomes too big, the header should be naturally stuck at the top of the screen, the footer at the bottom of the screen, and the middle part is taken by the content which should be scrollable.
Here is the code for the layout and I join some screens.

- Red: screen
- Blue: content header
- Green: content (Scrollview)
- Yellow:  content footer

[image: small content in scrollview]
[image: long content in scrollview]

```
<View style={styles.screen}>
    <View style={styles.contentHeader}>
        {contentHeader}
    </View>
    <ScrollView style={styles.content}>
        {content}
    </ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.contentFooter}>
        {contentFooter}
    </View>
</View>
```

My problem is that the ScrollView should take only the height required by its content but it does not.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FlatList` and use its `ListFoooterComponent` and `ListHeaderComponent` for rendering your header and footer you can also render these with `ScrollView` but its recommended to use `FlatList` for more performant and support.

Have a look at this to `FlatList`

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

Otherwise, you can use `stickyHeaderIndices` prop for rendering header in `ScollView` and place your footer outside of the ScrollView with these styles.

This will work

```
<View style={styles.screen}>
    <ScrollView style={styles.content} stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}>
       <View style={styles.contentHeader}>
            {contentHeader}
       </View>
       {content}
    </ScrollView>
    <View style={[styles.contentFooter, {position: 'absolute, bottom: 0}]}>
        {contentFooter}
    </View>
</View>
```

Comment: I ended  up using your second solution because I could  not make the content dynamic height with Flatlist (when I used flexGrow: 0 for some reasons the header and footer would disappear)
I removed the "position: 'absolute, bottom: 0" because I didn't want them to be at the bottom of the screen but just under the content like in the images.
Using stickyHeaderIndices the content scrolls under the header thought so it's not perfect.
Thanks for your help!